# Trying to run a chkdsk on c:\ automatically

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

Trying to run a chkdsk on all drives of the computer. Having issues with having C:\ start at all.

Trying to use SendKeys to answer "Would you like to schedule this volume to be checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)" but having no luck. Where am I going wrong?

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "BOHCdrivefix"

$FixCDrive = Start-Job -Name cDriveFix -ScriptBlock {chkdsk c:/f} 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('BOHCdrivefix')
sleep 3
$wshell.SendKeys('y') 
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
wait-job $FixCDrive
Receive-Job $FixCDrive | Out-File -FilePath D:\temp\cDriveFix.txt
shutdown -r -f -t 0
```

I would like to answer Y to the question then shutdown the PC and have it start the chkdsk

Comment: I'd not bother with `SendKeys`.  Use `… -ScriptBlock {echo 'y' | chkdsk c:/f}`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From [`Start-Job` document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job?view=powershell-5.0#description):

> The `Start-Job` cmdlet starts a Windows PowerShell background job on
>   the local computer.
>
> A Windows PowerShell background job runs a command **without
>   interacting with the current session**.

Hence, you can't send any key from the current session to a command running inside a background job. Sending a key must be inside the background job. Fortunately, `chkdsk.exe` accepts  use [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6) (which sends the results of the preceding command to the next command) as follows:

```
$FixCDrive = Start-Job -Name cDriveFix -ScriptBlock {Write-Output 'y'|chkdsk.exe c:/f}
```

or (using `echo` alias for `Write-Output` cmdlet):

```
$FixCDrive = Start-Job -Name cDriveFix -ScriptBlock {echo 'y'|chkdsk.exe c:/f}
```

**Please note**:

> ```
> The type of the file system is NTFS.
> Cannot lock current drive.
>
> Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
> process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be
> checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)
> ```

To answer "yes" to above question asked by `chkdsk c:/f` (*fix file system errors on the boot partition*), you must press **<kbd>Y</kbd>**, **followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>**.

Honestly said, I'm not sure whether  `Write-Output` cmdlet sends <kbd>Enter</kbd> into the pipeline. If not, force output of the new line as follows:

```
Write-Output "y$([System.Environment]::NewLine)"|chkdsk.exe c:/f}
```